# Not able to access the audio while simultaneously accessing the image bit map

Tags: javascript, audio, getusermedia

I am using the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to access my personal microphone and web camera. I am able to access my images through my webcamera and display it on my html page. however, i am not able to simulatenously play the audio.

I tried to first play the audio with the stream variable being set for the video srcObject. This worked great. However, when I changed the srcObject for my video to the imagebitmap, my code has not played the audio simultaneously.
I am getting an error in the console:Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

In this instance, you can ignore my jsonresponse as it is not doing anything other than returning a phrase. I'm first trying to access the audio chunks and imagebitmap properly.
Here's the code:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <style>
        #localVideo {
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
    </style>
    <center><video id="processedVideo" autoplay playsinline></video></center>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-peer/9.11.1/simplepeer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const constraints = {
            video: true,
            audio: {
                echoCancellation: true,
                noiseSuppression: true,
                autoGainControl: true,
                // Set the desired bitrate (e.g., 128 kbps)
                deviceId: {
                  exact: "default"
                }
            },
        };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then(stream => {
                //document.getElementById('processedVideo').srcObject = stream;
                const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                //const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
                const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(videoTrack);

                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);


                // Function to handle rendering imageBitmap into srcObject
                function renderImage(imageBitmap) {
                    console.log('Received video frame:', imageBitmap);
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = imageBitmap.width;
                    canvas.height = imageBitmap.height;
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0, imageBitmap.width, imageBitmap.height);
                    const newStream = canvas.captureStream();
                    document.getElementById('processedVideo').srcObject = newStream;
                }

                // Create a single Audio element for playback
                console.log(mediaRecorder);

                // Example: Grabbing video frames at intervals
                setInterval(() => {
                    imageCapture.grabFrame()
                        .then(imageBitmap => {
                            renderImage(imageBitmap);
                            fetch('/image', {
                                method: 'PUT',
                                headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", "X-CSRFtoken": "{{ csrf_token }}" },
                                body: JSON.stringify({ image: imageBitmap })
                            })
                                .then(response => response.json())
                                .then(result => {
                                    console.log(result);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.error('Error grabbing frame:', error));
                }, 200); // Adjust the interval as needed

                // Start recording audio
                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                    // Play audio chunk directly from MediaStream
                    var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
                    console.log('Received audio chunk:', blobUrl);
                    const audioElement = new Audio(blobUrl); // Create Audio element
                    audioElement.play();
                };
                mediaRecorder.start(1000); // Adjust the interval as needed
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error));
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```